# Linking text layers in sketch

Tags: text, typography, sketch-app

I have a text layer and other one is also a text layer applied Gaussian blur.

Is there any way we can link two text layer such that as soon as we change one text layer text, other gaussian blurred text layer's text automatically changes?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide a demo file, or a further explanation how this can be of help & will save you time in your project.

Comment: Should this be tagged "typography"? (I’m not editing because: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37672/when-should-you-edit-tags)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Sketch user, but a quick google search reveals that [Sketch has symbols](https://sketchapp.com/docs/symbols/creating-symbols/). So, I would try that route.

You could create a symbol from the text, and add two instances of it, one blurred, and one not blurred.  Then if you edit the master, the instances will update.

Nearly all vector image editing software has similar functionality: Illustrator and Sketch call it a symbol.  CorelDraw and Inkscape call it a clone.

Comment: I am an old time user of sketch i know about symbols but when i say link i mean it by when we link two layers in after effects using pickwhip and later layers are dpendant upon the property they were linked with.

Comment: For us sketch users not familiar with AE, can you describe in more detail the functionality you're looking for and how it'd differ from using a symbol?